# What is the best way to feed a Hungry Aura Node?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thaumcraft

I was wondering if my Hungry Aura Node gets more aspects efficient if I feed the Node with crafting tables one at a time or a stack at a time. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They get at most 1 aspect at a time so feeding them in one at a time is more efficient.

(Source: being insane:
[image: Insanity]
)